# Why are the arguments to this function still a tuple?

Tags: swift

I have an extension to Dictionary that adds `map`, `flatMap`, and `filter`.  For the most part it's functional, but I'm unhappy with how the arguments to the transform and predicate functions must be specified.

First, the extension itself:

```
extension Dictionary {
    init<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(elements: S) {
        self.init()

        for element in elements {
            self[element.0] = element.1
        }
    }

    func filter(@noescape predicate:(Key, Value) throws -> Bool ) rethrows -> [Key:Value] {
        return [Key:Value](elements:try lazy.filter({
            return try predicate($0.0, $0.1)
        }))
    }
}
```

Now then, since the `predicate` argument is declared as `predicate:(Key, Value)`, I would expect the following to work:

```
["a":1, "b":2].filter { $0 == "a" }
```

however, I have to actually use:

```
["a":1, "b":2].filter { $0.0 == "a" }
```

This is kind of confusing to use since the declaration implies that there are two arguments to the predicate when it's actually being passed as a single tuple argument with 2 values instead.

Obviously, I could change the filter function declaration to take a single argument (`predicate:(Element)`), but I really prefer it to take two explicitly separate arguments.

Any ideas on how I can actually get the function to take two arguments?

Comment: you can simplify your initialiser using forEach `elements.forEach({self[$0.0] = $0.1})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using closures without type declaration, the compiler has to infer the type. If you are using only `$0` and not `$1`, the compiler thinks that you are declaring a closure with only one parameter.

This closure then cannot be matched to your `filter` function. Simple fix:

```
let result = ["a":1, "b":2].filter { (k, _) in k == "a" }
```

Now also remember that tuples can be passed to functions and automatically match the parameters:

```
func sum(x: Int, _ y: Int) -> Int {
   return x + y
}

let params = (1, 1)
sum(params)
```

Then the behavior with `["a":1, "b":2].filter { $0.0 == "a" }` can be explained by type inferring. There are two possibilities and the compiler just chose the wrong one because it thought you want to have a closure with one argument only - and that argument had to be a tuple.

Comment: Yep, and I remember this when you mentioned it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a comparison function to allow you to compare a `Dictionary.Element` and a `Key`

```
func ==<Key: Hashable,Value>(lhs:Dictionary<Key,Value>.Element, rhs:Key) -> Bool {
  return lhs.0 == rhs
}
```

Comment: Your version (using the built-in CollectionType.filter) returns `[Element]` whereas my version returns `[Key:Value]`  Ie., the built-in version returns an Array, not a Dictionary.

Comment: `return lhs.0 == rhs`